# Show that $f : (0, \pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sin^2x$ for all $x ∈ (0, \pi)$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $f : (0, \pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sin^2x$ for all $x ∈ (0, \pi)$ is uniformly
continuous.

Normally I try something like $ x = \sqrt{n}$ and $ y = \sqrt{n+1}$ to analyze $f$ at $(0, \pi)$. It's not working, can someone solve this?

Comment: It's actually uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb R$ after we define $f(0)=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f:(0,\pi)\to\mathbb R$ has limits as $x\to0$ and $x\to\pi$, so we may extend it to a continuous function $\bar f:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb R$. This is a continuous function on a closed interval, so it is automatically uniformly continuous. Since $f$ is just the restriction of $\bar f$ to $(0,\pi)$, it is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)=-{{sin^2x}\over x^2}+2cosx{sinx \over x}$. This implies that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=1$ and $f'$ is bounded.MVT implies that  there exists $M$ such that $|f'(x)|<M$. You have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|, x,y \in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: lim sinx/x=1 when x approches 0